# Is there a workaround in sqlalchemy for loading a table from DB without any primary keys?

Tags: python, mysql, orm, sqlalchemy

I have a situation where i load all tables from legacy database. but it gives an error since it does not have any primary keys.

Can anyone give me a solution for this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the primary key information to the autoloaded table.

e.g.

```
class Subscrib(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'mytable'
    __table_args__ = {'autoload' : True}

    thepk = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Comment: @GHZ care to elaborate?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know in which way I should elaborate